# How to add common attributes to sequelize models?

Tags: express, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am trying to use hooks in sequlize to add common attributes to models,
I have defined a global hook as follows,

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  sequelizeClient.addHook('beforeDefine', (attributes) => {
    var defaultAttributes = {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      createdBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      updatedBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      deletedBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      }
    };
    Object.assign(attributes, defaultAttributes);
    //return attributes;
  });
};
```

But even the hook get fired the attributes are still not added to the model. I got the idea to add hooks for common attributes from here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4383. What I am doing wrong here? or Is there any better way to add common attributes?

Please note that I am using mysql as backend database. The sequelize model I am using is as follows.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const person = sequelizeClient.define('person', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  person.associate = function (models) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
  };

  return person;
};
```